# Im am unable to pip install modules. Mac Big Sur

Tags: python, pip, pygame, python-3.8

The general way I pip install modules is:  python3 -m pip install program_name --user

I am running Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.3 with an m1 chip.

some modules download, some others give me this massive error (this is only part of it since its too big to post on stack overflow):

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-jnuk8oje
         cwd: /private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/
    Complete output (27 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using Darwin configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/setup.py", line 318, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "/private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/buildconfig/config.py", line 221, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "/private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 131, in main
        [DependencyProg('SDL', 'SDL_CONFIG', 'sdl2-config', '2.0', ['sdl'])],
      File "/private/var/folders/5z/4tbbd4fn2cb3_6frql6qxyz40000gn/T/pip-install-3xvsm4fq/pygame_c004e27d19944143a00498e6db5c77cb/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 39, in __init__
        self.ver = config[0].strip()
    IndexError: list index out of range
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/b8/06e02c7cca7aec915839927a9aa19f749ac17a3d2bb2610b945d2de0aa96/pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=8b1e7b63f47aafcdd8849933b206778747ef1802bd3d526aca45ed77141e4001 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

 Running setup.py clean for pygame
Failed to build pygame
Installing collected packages: pygame
    Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
```

I know people have had similar issues. I've tried to use their provided solutions but they seem to not work for me. many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and then install the dependencies:

`brew install sdl2 sdl2_gfx sdl2_image sdl2_mixer sdl2_net sdl2_ttf`

Comment: This is mostly correct, but I believe they would also need to build a version of pygame after a recent patch - https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2636. So pulling 2.0.1 from pip wouldn’t work even with the dependencies.